# How do I add my own message to the Firefox status bar using extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

actually I am developing one project with front end UI design using extjs. But when my project is loading on the Mozilla browser, on the status bar, done has not been displayed to all the pages. How can I add my own messages to the Firefox status bar using extjs?

Answer (score 5):

There are two answers to this question:
First, you don't even need extjs, you can just use javascript's window.status (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.status) to add your own text.

However...

Firefox by default disables the ability to change that status, and it has to be re-enabled on each browser in order for you to be able to see those changes.